# Non-existence of convex neighbourhoods in $L^p(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

**Problem**
Let $0<p<1$, show that the neighbourhoods $\{f \in L^p(0,1):||f||_p<\epsilon\}$ of the zero function are not convex.

I am pretty stuck with this problem. If I've understood the statement of the exercise correctly, for each $\epsilon>0$, I have to show that there are $f,g$ with $||f||_p, ||g||_p <\epsilon$ but with $||\alpha f+(1-\alpha)g||_p \geq \epsilon$ for some $0 <\alpha<1$. I have no idea how to construct this example, I would appreciate hints or suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show that the $p$ norm $\|(x, y)\|_p = (|x|^p + |y|^p)^{1/p}$ is not convex in $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find an example in $\mathbb R^2$  first, i.e., $f,g\in \mathbb R^2$ with $|f|_p,|g|_p\le 1$ and $|(f+g)/2|_p>1$. Then use this to construct functions $f,g$.

Comment: I couldn't follow your suggestion, I don't understand why constructing the functions first in $\mathbb R^2$ makes things easier. Could I have another hint/suggestion?

Comment: Did you even try? Otherwise: No.